# What is the minimum SSD partition offset in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

I had a hard drive failure and replaced it with a new SSD followed by restoring in bare-metal fashion from Windows Home Server. I allowed the restore process to handle formatting the new drive.
The restoration worked quite well. I checked drive alignment with Paragon Partition Manager, and it responded "OK."
The offset on the system partition, however is only 32,768 bytes -- eight 4K sectors.
I've Googled until I'm blue in the face, but I cannot find out if this offset is adequate or even necessary for best SSD operation. Some say that alignment is not truly necessary on SSDs, but I find no comment at all on partition offset for SSDs

Answer (score 0):

Its on a power of 2 sector though should be fine.
Almost all ssd are 512 sectors so it shouldn't matter.

All physical devices are required to allow sectors 1-63 to be reserved.
Usually for special boot loaders, sometimes viruses hide here.  Mainly unused space here in the modern era.

Answer (score 0):

On a non-boot disk, you can even manually create a raw partition from offset 0 and Windows will recognize it as a volume. On a boot disk, it should be a multiple of the sector size (usually 512 bytes). The default of 1024 KiB is fine.